# Simple Gateway Using Spring Cloud Gateway - ProxyExchange

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I wanted to write a simple gateway using spring cloud, so that requests to a third party would appear to come from my service (as I have done so in the past with Zuul).

The example on the [github page](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-gateway.adoc) and likewise in the [official docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__building_a_simple_gateway_using_spring_mvc.html) seems to be exactly what I want. i.e. a simple controller route to proxy all requests to a given route:

```
@GetMapping("/proxy/path/**")
public ResponseEntity<?> proxyPath(ProxyExchange<?> proxy) throws Exception {
  String path = proxy.path("/proxy/path/");
  return proxy.uri(home.toString() + "/foos/" + path).get();
}
```

But the problem I have, is that the artefact `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` does not include `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.mvc.ProxyExchange`.

To get the `ProxyExchange`, I need to include the artefact `spring-cloud-gateway-mvc`, which is not compatible with `spring-cloud-starter-gateway`. Including these two things together causes the following error:

```
***************************************************
Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway 
at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency.
***************************************************
```

---

So, I'm forced to use the following two dependencies to get a basic Gateway to work:

- `spring-cloud-gateway`
- `spring-cloud-gateway-mvc`

Which, works fine, untill I need to use the `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.*` packages somewhere else in the project, which means that I need to include:

- `spring-cloud-gateway-core`, OR
- `spring-cloud-starter-gateway`

Which means that I'm back to the *incompatability banner*.

---

Is there anyway to use the simple API gateway features with just the `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` dependency, as the documentation implies should be possible? The version I'm using **2.0.0.RC1**.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-gateway', version: '2.0.0.RC1'
```

Comment: The documentation does not imply gateway works with Spring MVC. It's currently not possible

Comment: @spencergibb Ah righty - incompatibilty banner probably should have tipped me off there. Would there be a reccomended strategy to construct a simple Gateway in spring-cloud?

Comment: @spencergibb is it on the roadmap to make the gateway work with Spring MVC?