# Spring boot minimal proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, proxy

I have an micro services architecture that's laid out like this:

UI <-> Spring-boot-rest-app1 <-> Spring-boot-rest-app2 <-> Datastore

app1 takes care of some rest related stuff (validation, converting objects, etc) and app2 handles talking to the datastore. The final result is returned to the UI.

However for a particular endpoint, the POST payload is massive (JSON array of 80k objects (10 keys each roughly)).

For this particular endpoint, I'd like spring-boot-rest-app1 to not bother with the serialization of the post payload, and pass it directly to Spring-boot-rest-app2. The overhead of serializing this twice isn't worth it, and I'd like to find out if serializing it once is tolerable.

Currently the route is defined as such in app1:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Do long operation")
@PostMapping(value = "/route", produces = "application/json")
public Result longOperation(@RequestBody CumbersomeObject input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    validate(input);// for example
    return app2.connector.longOperation2(input); // for example
}
```

[I attempted to pull ProxyExchange.java into my application directly](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/spring-cloud-gateway-master/spring-cloud-gateway-mvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/mvc/ProxyExchange.java), and invoke it as such:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/route", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> proxy(ProxyExchange<Object> proxy) {
    return proxy.uri("${url.app2}/app2Route").post();
}
```

But spring complained about it not having an init method. I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103964/simple-gateway-using-spring-cloud-gateway-proxyexchange) which suggested that I can't directly add the gateway stuff as a dependency.

I don't really need to preserve too many properties of a proxy, I just need the most lightweight way for app1 to send a request to app2 with minimal serialization & overhead.

Naturally I don't mind sacrificing type safety, just looking to bring app1 latency down as much as possible.

Unfortunately due to the existing codebase I'm somewhat restricted in the architectural changes I can make.

Comment: Take a byte array in, and send that byte array?

Comment: If you are using Jackson you can toggle serialization and deserialization using the properties here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html or probably look at Zuul https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Comment: I’m having a lot of trouble understanding how the inflection logic works with boot. I was thinking about doing a byte array but I want to prevent an O(n) operation if there’s a constant time operation available. I’d imagine it’d be something like, just a string or some internal object. However the object is internally represented would be ideal, but I’m finding it difficult to understand what code the annotations map too.

Comment: Maybe something like "Object" or even something HTTPServletRequestEtc something like that?

Comment: Trying "Object" gives me an object represented as a LinkedHashMap, can I avoid the computation required to get to this point?

Comment: Why not use Feign Client: `@FeignClient(name="otherServiceName")` and send the request directly through a simple proxy class.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the FeignClient strategy would work really well as it's already part of this codebase, but it's unclear to me what Object I would put in the method header that neither feign or spring would spend a bunch of time trying to serialize. Do you think you could post an example of how to do this?

Comment: I think a custom decoder/encoder pair that do nothing but pass through the raw JSON. I've not had cause for this use case so don't have a project ready to spin up that matches your need. Give me a complete starting point and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn this is another thread I'll pull on. Do you know where source of where this encoding/decoding happen? That way I'll have a good idea what an optimal encoding/decoding pair looks like.

Comment: Start here: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#decoders